# how to compare and merge 2 dfs with different number of instances and get a column from the second df in the first?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dfs i want to merge, no common id columns between them

columns of interest in df1: date, winner, loser, winner_score, loser_score

columns of interest in df2: date, winner, loser, winner_score, loser_score, winner_odds, loser_odds

the 2 dfs don't have the same number of instances and instances in df2 are present in df1 but in different order

I want to get the winner_odds, loser_odds from df2 and have them in df1 in the correct instances, so I think I need to check when the dates of the 2dfs are the same and winner, loser, winner_score and loser_score are equal between the 2 dfs

Not sure if the solution is pretty easy or too difficult but how to approach it?

df1

```
date        winner  loser   w_elo   l_elo   w_sets  l_sets
2020-03-20  542     440     1000    1100        3       1
2020-03-20  440     408     1100     900        3       0
2020-03-20  542     408     1000     900        3       2
2020-03-21  408     302      900     900        3       1
2020-03-21  440     408     1100     900        3       1
2020-03-21  408     542      900    1000        3       2
2020-03-22  900     804     1000    1200        3       1
2020-03-22  408     542      900    1000        3       2
2020-03-22  900     760     1000     850        3       0
```

df2

```
date        winner  loser   w_odds  l_odds  w_sets  l_sets
2020-03-20  542     440     1.75     2.10       3       1
2020-03-20  542     408     1.71     2.0        3       2
2020-03-20  440     408     1.53     2.37       3       0
2020-03-21  408     302     1.83     1.83       3       1
2020-03-21  408     542     1.66     2.30       3       2
2020-03-21  440     408     1.57     2.25       3       1
2020-03-22  900     760     1.33     3.00       3       0
2020-03-22  408     542     2.2      1.77       3       2
```

Comment: Do not always focus on yourself, but think about what those who may want to help you may need: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I assumed my question was descriptive enough, what is it lacking?

Comment: As soon as you are able to formulate the problem comprehensibly and reproducible, you will probably be able to solve it yourself.

Comment: I didn't mention I'm a beginner so I can't understand if this is too hard for me atm. Do you think my description is so bad that you did not understand what I have and what I'm looking to achieve?

Comment: I think what you need is df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on=["date","winner", "loser"], but as mentioned an example table would help

Comment: I was convinced the answer would be something quite hard. I added some sample tables, does that help?